# Execute javascript within webpage with selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, javascript, html, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to execute a javascript method on a webpage with the selenium WebDriver. I am able to execute my own script on the page, but not call the method from the page's HTML. Here is the HTML

```
    function Search(){
        if(check(document.forms[0],"searchResults")){
        var fieldCode = "";
        var fieldText = "";

        if((document.forms[0].elements['prrSearchVO.selectedSearchCriteria.prrNumber'].value =="") && (!isPRRNoSelected()))
        {
            alert('PRR No. must be a selected field.');
            unSelectAllOptions(document.forms[0].availableFieldsListArray);
            unSelectAllOptions(document.forms[0].selectedFieldsList);
        }
        else
        {
            document.forms[0].excelRequested.value = "false";
            document.forms[0].action = "prrSearchResults.do";
            document.forms[0].submit();
        }
    }
}
```

If i attempt to submit the form manually it does not load properly. I can execute my own javascript using the code below. How can I execute the "Search" function from the page?

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('fromIssueDate').removeAttribute('readOnly')");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you shouldn't execute javascript using WebDriver unless you *really* have no other option. Why doesn't the submit work? what did you try? In my experience sometimes `click` doesn't trigger form submission, so instead you use `submit` on the form element. Note that if you `submit` on a non-form element its a no-op. So something like below should work,

```
    WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.id("email"));
    WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("password"));
    WebElement submit = driver.findElement(By.id("submit"));
    email.sendKeys("John");
    email.password("foo");
    submit.submit();
```

Going back to your original question, is `Search()` a global function? Then you could do something like below, however like I said, `WebDriver` doesn't recommend you invoke javascript since that's not how real users would interact with your application

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("window.Search();");
```

Comment: I tried setting the values of the form via javascript and then submitting the form, but the page returns an error. The purpose is automating report downloading, not testing. Working now, thanks!