# scraping JS rendered webpage where script has integrity attribute

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I want to scrape a JS rendered webpage with selenium python. 
The script is defined with a relational path and "integrity" attribute. 
How should I execute the script with subresource integrity using selenium?

Ex:

```
<script src="assets/vendor-2e3d10a9f3ccf562fe4f34aee7a18622.js" integrity="sha256-xP99abQmJgmWEHTx100iRFdOo72VVB9442T4wwCVjN0= sha512-tpwt1fE6brHds77JD1mNjxVlPDOzt7MpHrmIMa+seXXpoq3pXg0JYpfFR015YcNZdw8MEsjTuzMnr1RIglfhKg=="></script>
```

I have tried the following

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
innerHTML = browser.execute_script("assets/vendor-2e3d10a9f3ccf562fe4f34aee7a18622.js")
```

This results in

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error:
>   Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected
>   token

Can you please help me figure out

1. how to specify the complete path to the script
2. how to give the integrity attribute in execute_script

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with web-scraping. Your question is about executing a script in the webpage. If you phrase your question that way, you will get some answers. Here is one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30924678/3124333 (second half of the answer).

Comment: @SiKing well, the problem is how to execute such a script using selenium. My goal is to scrap the data (inner HTML) rendered with this script.

Comment: You want to read the contents of the file and pass that to execute_script.

Comment: @pguardiario the JS file contains multiple functions, there is no easy way of passing the content to the execute_script.

Comment: @pguardiario I found how to inject the whole JS code in the execute_script, but am now facing problems with selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
 which seems to be due to escapes "\" and mixed up singles quotes in JS code